# Different link on both images

Tags: html, css, svg, hyperlink

Good day! how can I put a different link on both images. check and paw are references to different pages. How to solve this problem? This is a test image, the svg will not work.

Thank you in advance for your help.

example jsfiddle.net/Fateol/jpd5hrbo/3

Comment: are u using this image on canvas ?

Comment: wrap each image in a different <a> tag.

Comment: one picture overlaps the other and the one that is below the overlap, though it can be seen

Comment: Add a [mcve] to this question, i.e. not a link please.

Comment: example  https://jsfiddle.net/Fateol/jpd5hrbo/3/ 
building can be a mouse move, and when the buildings go at each other should be able clicking on the visible area

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of `map` tag.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Definition and Usage
The  tag is used to define a client-side image-map. An image-map is an image with clickable areas.

The required name attribute of the  element is associated with the 's usemap attribute and creates a relationship between the image and the map.

The  element contains a number of  elements, that defines the clickable areas in the image map.

***Sample code***

```
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

for more details [check this](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/)

Comment: example jsfiddle.net/Fateol/jpd5hrbo/3 building can be a mouse move, and when the buildings go at each other should be able clicking on the visible area

Comment: using the map element you can give two different link for single image. Put href="your link" with  the area  element for the links

Comment: this is a different picture, pictures can move
 
example jsfiddle.net/Fateol/jpd5hrbo/3

Answer (score -3):

Just cut the image in 2 pieces and try this.
' <  img src="upload the im age on an image hosting and copy  here your direct lin k" width="300" height ="255" alt="" /> ' 
This w as the first part. Now take the other half of your image and do the same step.

Answer (score -3):

Theres the html code on the page.
Make sure you cutted the image in a half. And repeat the procees for the 2 halfs.